# No modifier keys registered in Firefox Mac during external drag and drop onto window

Tags: javascript, firefox, html5-draggable

In Safari the following code shows what modifier keys are being pressed when dragging and dropping. But in Firefox the modifier keys are not being registered.

Test code, https://jsfiddle.net/omofkgdv/21/.

[image]

*The Command key is being tested here but none of the modifier keys (Shift, Alt, CTRL, or Command) register.*

```js
(function() {
  var element = document.getElementById("dropzone");
  var useCapture = true;
  
  dragHandler = function(e) {
    e = e || event;
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("ctrl:" + e.ctrlKey + ", shift:" + e.shiftKey + ", alt:" + e.altKey + ", meta:" + e.metaKey + ", type:" + e.type);
    //console.log(e);
  }

  element.addEventListener("dragenter", dragHandler, useCapture);
  element.addEventListener("dragleave", dragHandler, useCapture);
  element.addEventListener("dragover", dragHandler, useCapture);
  element.addEventListener("dragexit", dragHandler, useCapture);
  element.addEventListener("dragend", dragHandler, useCapture);
  element.addEventListener("drop", dragHandler, useCapture);

}())
```

```css
.dropzone {
  color:white;
  background-color:#2662ff;
  left:5px;
  right:5px;
  top:5px;
  bottom:5px;
  padding:5px;
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
}
.dropzone:-moz-drag-over {
  outline: 2px dashed black;
}
.dropzone:drag-over {
  outline: 2px dashed green;
}
.dropzone:dragover {
  outline: 2px dashed black;
}
```

```html
<div id="dropzone" class="dropzone">Drop external file here</div>
```

OSX 10.11, Firefox 58

**Steps to reproduce**
1. Open browser and add event handlers to document (see example)
2. Open finder and drag over the document or element
3. While dragging hold down shift, alt, ctrl or command key
4. Release the mouse button

**Expected Result**
Event reflects the modifier keys that are pressed

**Actual Result**
In specific test provided the event the modifier key values are all false. Note if the window has focus the modifier keys sometimes show up (needs more testing for when it works). See gif and link to example provided.

Comment: Not certain what the question is?

Comment: I guess if this is a bug or is there something else I need to do.

Comment: Have you read the specification as to what the expected result is? What is the result at Chromium or Chrome? Is the OS mac? What is the expected result? Can you include a written description of each step to reproduce the result that you experience with the code at the text of the Question?

Comment: Yep but maybe I missed something. I have it working in the project I'm working on but the modifier keys are always false on Firefox. I'm looking for any workarounds. For example, there is a relatedTarget on the drag events that is supposed to be a related mouse event but that is null in my tests.

Comment: Can you include the steps to reproduce the issue as text at the question with links to the specification relevant to the present case?

Comment: Just tried at Chromium and Firefox. Both render `ctlr:true` at *nix. Have you tried at a different OS?

Comment: I've updated the post with steps to reproduce. Glad it works on *nix. Only tested on Mac.

Comment: _"In specific test provided the event does not contain any modifier key values."_ Do you mean the values are set to `false`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163915/discussion-between-1-21-gigawatts-and-guest271314).

Comment: Tested on FF58 on osX, and only the drop event seems to register these keys, and even, only if it was initialised (i.e if the key was pressed) after the drag event started (i.e after dragenter). Sounds like a bug to me, possibly related to OS default actions in such cases (that I don't know btw).

Comment: If Firefox has focus sometimes I get modifier key values other than false. If you test it anyway other than as shown in the gif it's inconsistent (so yes, if you repress the key sometimes you get true values). For my application, the user drags an image onto the browser just like in the gif.

Comment: I guess best move is to open an issue on firefox's bugzilla. For workarounds, I couldn't find any if you want to get it for all these events: I thought using a parallel mousemove handler, but FF will fire this event only after the drag event ended... (could still be useful for the drop event, but that's about it.)

Comment: I got a few minutes to dig in mozilla's bugzilla and found [this old one](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=474067) which is still open, but links to [this one](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=549891) we should have fixed it for osX, but that all was 8 years ago (an eternity). So you might well want to open a new issue.